# Change event in text box while editing is still in progress

Tags: javascript, jquery

Wile the `change` event in jQuery can be used to monitor changes in `<input />` element contents, it is only triggered after the user switches focus to somewhere else:

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to  elements,  boxes and  elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.

Is there an event that is triggered when the user makes an edit, but the cursor still remains within the text box? Preferably jQuery, but a native browser event or even a nasty workaround would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in newer browsers the `input` event fires on all input, otherwise there's the key events,

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('input', handler);
$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', handler);
$('input[type="text"]').on('keydown', handler);
$('input[type="text"]').on('keypress', handler);
$('input[type="text"]').on('paste', handler);
```

[input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input)
[keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/keyup)
[keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/keydown)
[keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/keypress)
[paste](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.onpaste)